# Error when passing function as an argument in C++

Tags: c++, function, random

I encountered this strange thing with with C++ when i tried to pass a function as an argument to another one. the problem here is that it works but not giving me the expected result.
here's my code (msvc2013):

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
using namespace std;

#include "stdafx.h"

uint32_t random_color()
{
    uint8_t r = rand() % 255;
    uint8_t g = rand() % 255;
    uint8_t b = rand() % 255;
    uint32_t rgb = ((uint32_t)r << 16 | (uint32_t)g << 8 | (uint32_t)b);

    return rgb;
}

void print_rgb(uint32_t(*color_generator)() = &random_color)
{
    std::cout << color_generator << std::endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        print_rgb();
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

the purpose of this code is more complicated, but this is a minimal example.

**Question :** although as you see, there was an `srand(time(NULL));` in order for `rand()` to change values, it dosen't !

so , at the 5 times, I got the same value ! 
[image: output]

Is there any reason for this ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: dont use `rand()` if you need random numbers. The problem is that you seed the rng inside the loop with the same seed and the time does not change between two iterations. There are dozens of duplicates on this on SO.

Comment: This isn't the presenting problem, but call `srand` once only. Don't call it every time through the loop.

Comment: If it doesn't give the expected result then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looks like you are printing value of pointer to function, your code should be:

```
std::cout << color_generator() << std::endl;
```

Comment: didn't work ! same output 5 times.

Comment: @YassinNasri move `srand()` out of loop, but better use more reliable random number generator

Answer (score 3):

Nothing weird is going on. This code prints out the address passed into it, and the address isn't random.

```
void print_rgb(uint32_t(*color_generator)() = &random_color)
{
    std::cout << color_generator << std::endl;
}
```

You either need to call the function, here or, if your intention was that appending it to the stream would call it, instead implement something similar to a stream manipulator.

Comment: any suggestion how to do that ? @Slava answer didn't work either !